# Problem connecting 10W led + Led driver Directly Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, led

can anyone give me an advice on connecting an 10W led + 12 volt drive to an Arduino Uno? it works without the board but when i tried to connect to Uno it doesn't work anymore. Thankyou

Comment: advice: don't do it.

Comment: Not unless you tell us what equipment you are using...

Comment: Yes, Thankyou, I'm using Led Driver Driver
Input Voltage: 12-24V DC
Output Voltage: 9-12V
Output Current: 900mA+-5%
can support 10pcs high power 10W led 3 in serial and 3 in parallel 
 http://www.ebay.com/itm/331653946252?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=540791276944&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Answer (score 3):

To operate LED using Arduino you will need a switch that can be operated using electronic switch like transistor, Mosfet or Relay board.
More easy and reliable option would be using Relay Board.

You can visit this link and can get more idea....

http://www.electroschematics.com/8975/arduino-control-relay/

Comment: wow, thankyou so much, this is what i bought from ebay an Led driver
Input Voltage: 12-24V DC
Output Voltage: 9-12V
Output Current: 900mA+-5%
can support 10pcs high power 10W led 3 in serial and 3 in parallel 
 http://www.ebay.com/itm/331653946252?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=540791276944&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a switch such as a transistor, and capable of handling 10W, to be driven by the Arduino and connect/disconnect the LED to an external 12v supply. There are many examples on the web. Remember to connect the 12v and 5v grounds together.